# PHP: Localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I want to check in login page if one user already login in the system its go to index page. But the code i used had an error like this

> localhost redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

and this is my code to check the user is login or not. Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../pages/koneksi.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from tb_user where username = '$username';");
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $_SESSION['ID']=$user['ID'];
    header("location: index.php");
    die();
    } else {
       header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

And this is the index file

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../pages/koneksi.php';
//check session udah login apa belum
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from tb_user where username = '$username';");
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $_SESSION['ID']=$user['ID'];
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: can i have a look at `login.php` file

Comment: That's it sir @Abhishek

Comment: then `index.php` maybe. It would be good if both the file are there

Comment: you are checking if `$_SESSION['username']` is set , but after login you are not setting it instead you are setting `$_SESSION['ID']` , hence its redirecting ... Set the `$_SESSION['username']` and your issue will be fixed

Comment: If this is login.php so because$_session['username'] is null so that it run in else blockcodr forever

Comment: Why you are redirecting after login...

Comment: Thank you very much all, its work now @GyandeepSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this... On

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../pages/koneksi.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){header("location: login.php");}
?>
```

And on

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../pages/koneksi.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){header("location: index.php");}
?>
```

Don't add these code on same page... both code are opposite of each other.

If you add them in same page then if or else condition runs every page load....